# Azure function error file not found when deployed in Linux AZ function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to reading Json File in AZ function from source directory. Local when on windows machine its working fine but getting error File not found when deployed in Linux AZ function app. Reading Json file using below code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace FunctionAppBrands
{
    public static class FunctionGetData
    {
        [FunctionName("GetData")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "GetData")] HttpRequest req, 
            ILogger log)
        {
            
            
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string allText = GetData();
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(allText).Recordset;
            return new JsonResult(data);



        }
        
   private static string GetData()
    {
       //File Placed in souce directory folder ReadData
        string text= File.ReadAllText(@"ReadData\" "test.json");   
        return text;
    }
       
        public class Root
        {
            public List<Dictionary<string, object>> Recordset { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The source code you postet looks incomplete, can you update the File.ReadAllText method? Also, have you checked whether the file is present in the Linux AZ function app?

Comment: Hi Martin, This is my code somehow the file also not available when i deploy to linux function app. I am new to function app not sure whats not working here. I tried with Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) seems not working.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check (using Kudu or SSH) whether the file is present within the App Service. If not, you probably missed setting the copy to output directory for that file within the *.csproj:

...

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="test.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now ReadAllText will find the file - e. g. if it is within the root directory, this will work:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText("test.json");
```

I published a [working sample with .NET 6 on GitHub](https://github.com/mjisaak/azure-app-service-access-files).

Comment: When i publish my function to linux Azure function app its only showing host.json file in wwwroot folder.. I have setup the copy to output directory.

Comment: How do you publish your code? Is the rest of your application working?

Comment: Yes its working with my local. I published using VS

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FunctionDirectory` from `ExecutionContext context`.

You can update function method as below:

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]
    HttpRequest req,
    ExecutionContext context,
    ILogger log)
{
    var root = context.FunctionDirectory;
    ...
}
```

Note: If you are accessing file inside root folder, construct your path as below:

`Path.Combine(root, @"Templates", "TemplateFile.html");`

This will make sure that code works in both Windows and Linux.